# How to automate property setting in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

My `subversion` repository has a pre-commit hook that requires all files to have a SVN property before its commit.

I am setting this property manually making each addition of files and folders a 2-step commit.

How to automate this?

Comment: Whilst I can't help, the only property I use in SVN is the svn:extern one, I'll admit to being curious as to what properties you typically set and why you need one.

Comment: @Ray: `svn:mime-type` is another example. This is especially useful for HTTP links to HTML documents in the repository: without the correct mime type, your browser will show these as text files instead of rendering the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Automatic property setting](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props) section in the TortoiseSVN documentation.

You can either locally configure each client as already explained by Josh, or alternatively put the configuration in the repository with the `tsvn:autoprops` property. The latter only works for TortoiseSVN clients though.

The command line client doesn't support server-side configuration of autoprops. There are some change requests related to this, e.g. [issue 1974](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1974) and [issue 1813](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1813).

Answer (score 6):

This depends on your client.  In TortoiseSVN, for example, here are instructions for setting svn:eol-style on all .c, .cpp, and .h files:

1. Go under the Start Menu, under TortoiseSVN, under Settings. Under the General tab, click Edit.
2. Under [miscellany], uncomment `enable-auto-props = yes`
3. Under [auto-props], add the following lines:

   ```
   *.c = svn:eol-style=native
   *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
   *.h = svn:eol-style=native
   *.hpp = svn:eol-style=native
   ```

For the Subversion command-line client on Linux, edit `~/.subversion/config`, then do steps #2 and #3 above.

Comment: it didn't work for me, but it should be some problem with my tortoise or my configuration

Comment: the problem was I wrote `svn:needs-lock=*` instead of `svn:needs-lock=x`

Comment: Does these auto-props get applied on add or on commit? Server pre-commit hooks are still stopping me from committing, so I think I need to revert and re-add each file for the property to get set, but I hope there's and easier way

Comment: Never mind, just removed and added one of the offending files and its error message disappeared. So for anyone else coming along, these config changes only work for new additions. I'll have to ask a new question for "batch re-add uncommitted added files in tortoise svn" some time